# ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized. Browser Game

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are having some problems displaying the experience a player has from our database.

This is for a school project, would like some hints :)

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand CheckExp = new SqlCommand("SELECT Experience FROM Player WHERE UserID=@uid");

string uID = Session["userID"].ToString();

CheckExp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uID);

        try
        {

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader ExpReader = null;
            ExpReader = CheckExp.ExecuteReader();

            if (ExpReader.Read()) 
            {
                Label6.Text = ExpReader["Experience"].ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label6.Text=(ex.Message);

        }

        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't connect your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Just define your connection as a second parameter like;

```
SqlCommand CheckExp = new SqlCommand("SELECT Experience FROM Player WHERE UserID=@uid", connection);
```

Or you can assing your [`SqlCommand.Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like;

```
CheckExp.Connection = connection;
```

Comment: Personally I suggest - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252531/21061

Comment: @user3620202 Since you solved your problem, please delete your question because it doesn't even help future visitors. I delete my answer.

Comment: @Ian Why not? Deleted.

Comment: @Ian Oh damn.. `You have already deleted 5 of your own posts today; further deletes are blocked`